# how to fetch an otp or claim code from email using Rest Assured Java

Tags: java, rest-assured

how to fetch an otp or claim code from email using Rest Assured Java?

Description: I have a Create a lead api. Once I hit the api, an url is received on email which has basically an unique claim code.
Can some one please help me to fetch the email details?